# Can't create new entries in DB

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server

I am currently running 2 websites that share the same source code, changing only the DB and some minor aspects.

I recently launched my 2nd website and although everything appears to be running just fine I realized that I can't add new entries in the DB. It just gives me the message that the entry already exists, which is not true since there is only a few entries and I am obviously testing using unique entries. Another thing that I noticed is that the data that exists in the DB (I used an internal server to test things out) can be edited, which I assume that `UPDATE` statement is working but not `INSERT INTO` and `DELETE`. It appears that there is some problem with the connection/permission to add/delete new entries, while updating is fine.

All this is very strange as the code (PHP and JS) is exactly the same between websites and the only thing that changes is the VM I used for each of them, which makes me believe that the issue is somehow in the configuration of the webserver. I have replicated all the configurations from the other website, so I am not sure if I am missing something. Here's a list of all the configuration I have implemented:

- edited 000-default.conf (of Apache to set the new document root)
- changed the ownership of my app to www-data
- created a user group with myself in it and changed the group of all subdirectories/files to this group
- opened up the port 3306 for mysql

I honestly can't understand what is wrong, I am clearly missing some configuration setting but I have no clue what it might be. One thing that is different is the MySQL version between websites. The website that works is running this version:

> 5.7.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

While my new website is running this:

> 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Could this be an issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You wouldn't get that error message unless the row does already exist. There's no configuration setting that would cause it to happen erroneously.

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you're getting? The ability to UPDATE but not DELETE sounds like the problem is with the GRANTs to the MySQL username.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for your answer. I thought the problem could also be because of GRANTs, but I have all grants exactly the same in both websites:

`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost' `

I wrote the error only to show when the query finds an equal username, but the DB is nearly empty. I don't get it.